# CSS/HTML Div Resizing and Table positioning

Tags: javascript, css, html, html-table

I have 3 divs, the parent div, child div at the top and another on the bottom. Any help will be highly appreciated, here is what I want to achieve:

When the top div resizes/increases its size, the bottom div that contains a table will shrink but remain in its position. Please see below the mock up so that you can clearly visualize it.

[Here is my Mock Up Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1dDd.png)

Here is my JSFiddle:   https://jsfiddle.net/koykoys/t09v854r/8/

```js
$("#btnExpand").click(function(){
    $(#top).css("height","400px");
});
```

```css
.wrapper{
  height: 73vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

#top{
  border:2px solid blue;
  position:relative;
  height:100px  
}

#bottom{
  border:2px solid green;
  position:relative;
  height:100%"
}
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id "expand">
    <input id = "btnExpand" type="button" value="Expand Blue Div"/>
  </div>
  <div id="top"></div>
  </br>
  <div id "Download CSV">
    <button >
      Download CSV of Table
    </button>
  </div>
  <div id="bottom" style="border:2px solid green;position:relative;height:100%" >
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Firstname</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Jaranjan</td>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Jaranjan</td>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Jaranjan</td>
        <td>John</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Boom</td>
        <td>Panes</td> <td>John</td>
        <td>Jaranjan</td>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Jaranjan</td>
        <td>John</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Boom</td>
        <td>Panes</td> <td>John</td>
        <td>Jaranjan</td>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Jaranjan</td>
        <td>John</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Boom</td>
        <td>Panes</td> <td>John</td>
        <td>Jaranjan</td>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Jaranjan</td>
        <td>John</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Boom</td>
        <td>Panes</td> <td>John</td>
        <td>Jaranjan</td>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Jaranjan</td>
        <td>John</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Boom</td>
        <td>Panes</td> <td>John</td>
        <td>Jaranjan</td>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Jaranjan</td>
        <td>John</td>
      </tr>
    </table> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: Don't just make a fiddle, include code in the question it self. Better still use the `<>` button in the question editor to include a StackOverflow snippet in the question. It is like a fiddle, but in the question (or answer) it self. Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Ok , I will create jsfiddle, you can also check my mock up image that I attached, thanks :)

Comment: So you want all the element always stay in same page with 100% height?

Comment: @trungk18, yes, that is what is exactly what I want to achieve, all alements will retain their position inside the parent div.

The bottom table will only shrink its size when the top div increases its size,

Comment: Alright you show us what you have done first and we can see what we can do for you. :D

Comment: I already  created and added my JSfiddle :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your `wrapper height` to `auto`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btnExpand").click(function(){
      $('#top').animate({
        'height' : '400px'   
      });
   }); 
});
```

```css
.wrapper{
  width:100%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

#top{
  border:2px solid blue;
  position:relative;
  height:100px;
}
#bottom{
  border:2px solid green;
  position:relative;
  height:100%"
}
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
 <div id = "expand">
     <input id = "btnExpand" type="button" value="Expand Blue Div"/>
  </div>
   <div id="top"  >
  </div>
  </br>
   <div id = "Download CSV">
      <button >
      Download CSV of Table
      </button>
  </div>
  <div id="bottom" style="border:2px solid green;position:relative;height:100%" >
     <table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Firstname</th>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Jaranjan</td>
     <td>John</td>
    <td>Jaranjan</td>
     <td>John</td>
    <td>Jaranjan</td>
     <td>John</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Boom</td>
    <td>Panes</td> <td>John</td>
    <td>Jaranjan</td>
     <td>John</td>
    <td>Jaranjan</td>
     <td>John</td>


  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Boom</td>
    <td>Panes</td> <td>John</td>
    <td>Jaranjan</td>
     <td>John</td>
    <td>Jaranjan</td>
     <td>John</td>


  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Boom</td>
    <td>Panes</td> <td>John</td>
    <td>Jaranjan</td>
     <td>John</td>
    <td>Jaranjan</td>
     <td>John</td>


  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Boom</td>
    <td>Panes</td> <td>John</td>
    <td>Jaranjan</td>
     <td>John</td>
    <td>Jaranjan</td>
     <td>John</td>


  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Boom</td>
    <td>Panes</td> <td>John</td>
    <td>Jaranjan</td>
     <td>John</td>
    <td>Jaranjan</td>
     <td>John</td>


  </tr>


   
</table>

     
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this but the problem on this solution is that, the wrapper changes its sized, it should not change regardless of the height of 2 divs inside.

Comment: @ReymarkMatiraPanopio Welcome. Why are you increasing wrapper height using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Here's new js fiddle that works https://jsfiddle.net/whp257jp/

You had errors in your html markup. I fixed it.

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <div id="expand">
     <input id="btnExpand" type="button" value="Expand Blue Div"/>
  </div>
   <div id="top" >
  </div>
  <br/>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#btnExpand").click(function(){
  $('#top').css("height","400px");
});
```

It's not full solution for your task. I just made your code work.

Task that u given pretty hard for u as beginner. U need to learn css, html and jQuery more deeply to solve this task.

Comment: Thank you for the correcting my error, yes, I still needed more knowledge on this field :)

Answer (score 0):

`wrapper` height must be **auto**:

```
.wrapper{
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

And you've forgotten the double-quotes:

```
$("#top").height("400px");
```

Comment: Mark some of the answers as correct if your questions is solved